# Xamarin forms, Change map default visible region

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I change map default `VisibleRegion` without invoking `MoveToRegion()` method? (I mean start map with a specific area, not it's default visible region that is Rome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is configured to use location services, you can use `IsShowingUser="True"` in `Xaml` and map will show your location.

Also as described in [Map - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/#Map_Region_and_MapSpan) page:

> supplying a MapSpan instance to a map constructor sets the initial
>   view (center point and zoom level) of the map when it is loaded.

So you can use something like this

```
var map =  new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                 new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)));
```